recover data from lvm-thin
I had proxmox installed with a number of LVM thin volumes. After sudden failure, I'm trying to recover a database VM but all efforts to mount it or export it in some way have failed. I must add that the DB lv is LUKS encrypted but I haven't even gotten to the point where I can mount the volume.
root@ubuntu:~# vgs
  VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree  
  pve   1   9   0 wz--n- 1.74t <64.24g
root@ubuntu:~# lvs
  LV            VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  data          pve twi---tz--  <1.60t                                                    
  data_meta0    pve -wi-a----- 256.00m                                                    
  data_meta1    pve -wi-a----- <15.88g                                                    
  data_meta2    pve -wi-a----- <15.88g                                                    
  root          pve -wi-a-----  20.00g                                                    
  swap          pve -wi-a-----   4.00g                                                    
  vm-100-disk-0 pve Vwi---tz-- 266.00g data                                               
  vm-100-disk-1 pve Vwi---tz-- 266.00g data                                               
  vm-105-disk-0 pve Vwi---tz-- 100.00g data                                               
root@ubuntu:~# vgchange -ay pve -v
  5 logical volume(s) in volume group "pve" already active
  5 existing logical volume(s) in volume group "pve" monitored
  Activating logical volume pve/swap.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/swap.
  Activating logical volume pve/root.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/root.
  Activating logical volume pve/data.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/data.
  Creating pve-data_tmeta
  Loading table for pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Resuming pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Creating pve-data_tdata
  Loading table for pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Resuming pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/pve-data_tmeta
  Creating pve-data-tpool
  Loading table for pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Resuming pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Thin pool pve-data-tpool (252:7) transaction_id is 0, while expected 13.
  Removing pve-data-tpool (252:7)
  Removing pve-data_tmeta (252:5)
  Removing pve-data_tdata (252:6)
  Activating logical volume pve/vm-105-disk-0.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/vm-105-disk-0.
  Creating pve-data_tmeta
  Loading table for pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Resuming pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Creating pve-data_tdata
  Loading table for pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Resuming pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/pve-data_tmeta
  Creating pve-data-tpool
  Loading table for pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Resuming pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Thin pool pve-data-tpool (252:7) transaction_id is 0, while expected 13.
  Removing pve-data-tpool (252:7)
  Removing pve-data_tmeta (252:5)
  Removing pve-data_tdata (252:6)
  Activating logical volume pve/vm-100-disk-0.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/vm-100-disk-0.
  Creating pve-data_tmeta
  Loading table for pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Resuming pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Creating pve-data_tdata
  Loading table for pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Resuming pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/pve-data_tmeta
  Creating pve-data-tpool
  Loading table for pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Resuming pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Thin pool pve-data-tpool (252:7) transaction_id is 0, while expected 13.
  Removing pve-data-tpool (252:7)
  Removing pve-data_tmeta (252:5)
  Removing pve-data_tdata (252:6)
  Activating logical volume pve/vm-100-disk-1.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/vm-100-disk-1.
  Creating pve-data_tmeta
  Loading table for pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Resuming pve-data_tmeta (252:5).
  Creating pve-data_tdata
  Loading table for pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Resuming pve-data_tdata (252:6).
  Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/pve-data_tmeta
  Creating pve-data-tpool
  Loading table for pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Resuming pve-data-tpool (252:7).
  Thin pool pve-data-tpool (252:7) transaction_id is 0, while expected 13.
  Removing pve-data-tpool (252:7)
  Removing pve-data_tmeta (252:5)
  Removing pve-data_tdata (252:6)
  Activating logical volume pve/data_meta0.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/data_meta0.
  Activating logical volume pve/data_meta1.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/data_meta1.
  Activating logical volume pve/data_meta2.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/data_meta2.
  Activated 5 logical volumes in volume group pve.
  5 logical volume(s) in volume group "pve" now active
root@ubuntu:~# lvscan
  inactive          '/dev/pve/data' [<1.60 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/swap' [4.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/root' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-105-disk-0' [100.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-100-disk-0' [266.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-100-disk-1' [266.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/data_meta0' [256.00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/data_meta1' [<15.88 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/data_meta2' [<15.88 GiB] inherit

I've already ran lvconvert --repair pve/data and have also deleted some lvs that I don't really need to increase space. I've also reduced the size of swap and root successfully.
The vm disk I'm trying to recover is /dev/pve/vm-100-disk-1 I don't really care for all the rest
Any help is greatly appreciated. Happy to even pay.

Some discussions here https://github.com/jthornber/thin-provisioning-tools/issues/126 and some script here https://github.com/traktofon/thinpool-unscramble but I've never used it so you're on your own with those.

Thanks a lot for the pointers. I ran into a snug while working through the steps (extract the thinpool's metadata).
For some reason, mine's empty

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# thin_dump /dev/pve/data_meta0 > data_meta0.xml

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cat data_meta0.xml 
<superblock uuid="" time="0" transaction="0" flags="0" version="2" data_block_size="128" nr_data_blocks="26785664">
</superblock>


